# how to download source code for a specific cloudera distribution?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

The nice folks here at stackoverflow helped me figure out how to identify the specific cloudera release on my ubuntu development machine.  ( dpkg -l | grep cdh ).

Now I would like to fumble around the sources, but I am not sure where to go to download them. Let's say i want to download the hdfs sources (with cloudera mods for cdh5.3.0):

the version shown by dpkg is:

hadoop-hdfs                      2.5.0+cdh5.3.0+781-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.54~precise

Now if i go to this github repo:    https://github.com/cloudera/hadoop-hdfs
I don't see anything tag that contains the string  '5.3.0'.

So I'm stuck on where to look.   Any pointers would be most gratefully  appreciated.

Comment: It's Hadoop HDFS; CDH is their distro that includes HDFS. Download HDFS from the Apache site. It's obvious that github page isn't where they're keeping any current source anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.   Readers should note that the Apache site does indeed have source (which is great). But that source will not necessarily contain the patches that vendors like Cloudera, Hortonworks, etc. have applied.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options for downloading cloudera version specific source code.

**Options 1: From Maven repo**

https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.5.0-cdh5.3.0/hadoop-hdfs-2.5.0-cdh5.3.0-sources.jar

https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.5.0-cdh5.3.0/hadoop-common-2.5.0-cdh5.3.0-sources.jar

(Change the version and hadoop component name appropriately)

**Options 2: From tar ball repo**

Cloudera provides Hadoop relases in the form of tar balls (hadoop-x.x.x.tar.gz), this will contains both binary as well as source code. The same is available in the following Cloudera repository.

http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.3.0.tar.gz

Comment: Option 1 gives you separate source jars for each hadoop component, Option 2 gives a monolithic file. A source-only tarball is also provided in that archive, e.g. [hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.3.0-src.tar.gz](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.3.0-src.tar.gz).